# Is "utf-8-sig" suitable for decoding both UTF-8 and UTF-8 BOM?

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using the Python CSV library to read two CSV files.

One is encoded with UTF-8-BOM, another is encoded with UTF-8. In my practice, I found that both files could be read by using "utf-8-sig" as encoding type:

```
from csv import reader 
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    c_reader = reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    headers = next(c_reader)    
    for row in c_reader:
        print(row)
```

I want to confirm, is "utf-8-sig" suitable for decoding both UTF-8 and UTF-8 BOM?
I am using Python version 3.6 and 3.7. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The utf-8-sig codec will decode both utf-8-sig-encoded text and text encoded with the standard utf-8 encoding

```python
>>> s = 'Straße'
>>> utf8_sig = s.encode('utf-8-sig')
>>> utf8 = s.encode('utf')
>>> print(utf8_sig.decode('utf-8-sig'))
Straße
>>> print(utf8.decode('utf-8-sig'))
Straße
```

From the codecs [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode):

> Before any of the Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded BOM (which looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is written ... On decoding utf-8-sig will skip those three bytes if they appear as the first three bytes in the file.

The utf-8-sig encoding in most common in Windows environments.  If you're sharing files with users on mac or *nix systems, the standard utf-8 encoding is what they would expect to receive.

Comment: So lets see if I can summarize your suggestion: use `'utf-8-sig'` to read all UTF-8 files, use `'utf-8'` to write most files, and use `'utf-8-sig'` to write files that you know are going to be opened exclusively on Windows systems?

Comment: @MarkRansom it was more of an observation than a suggestion, but yes, I think that's a reasonable approach.  If I were pushed I'd be inclined to say plain UTF-8 everywhere, but tbh I don't know if it's possible to prevent Windows apps from using utf-8-sig even when utf-8 is the default encoding.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think when you ask Excel to save a .csv in UTF-8 it will put the signature on the file and there's no way to avoid it.  That makes it hard to achieve a world without signatures.

Comment: @MarkRansom Also Excel won't read a UTF-8 file without a BOM.  It will assume the localized ANSI encoding (Windows-1252 on U.S. Windows, for example).  Many Windows programs work this way with UTF-8.